# Why sleep control and vibrate control is necessary?

Tags: android, performance, gps

Am developing an android gps tracking application which runs for long ours.

As a process of research I was referring to similar kind of apps.

But I dint understood why the apps like this need sleep control and vibrate control permissions?

Can any one explain what can be the use of these two permission in these kind of apps? so that I will get better insight about approaches used.

Comment: My understanding is that these kind of apps are highly power consuming apps and that might be the reason for it. However your question is too broad for anybody to answer: Where to use: android, blackberry etc...How to use: depends on how you are writing the code...

Comment: thanks for the reply, I want to keep getting data every 30sec using requestlocationupdates() so will sleep control needed for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These apps needs vibrate permissions because they want to use vibrator feature **for any reason**. It's not important why. They want to do so, so they need to hold this permission.

Sleep control is to keep device on all the time, so the screen is not going off or dimmed where that app is running. One way to do so is to hold WAKE LOCK (and you need permission for this).

Comment: I read WAKE LOCK can be used to keep cpu and screen on FULL WAKE LOCK is that b'cauze we can't use gps if we dint keep it awake?

Comment: Yes, it's also the possibility. You can't get location updates if device is sleeping